# How to get more gentle (cloud like) noise?

Tags: terrain, perlin-noise

Recently I have started playing around with making terrain with perlin noise. Using [this library](https://github.com/wwwtyro/perlin.js)  I can make A fairly fast. However, it is to squiggly to be desirable. What I want to achieve is B, where you can see more convincing slopes with the softer noise.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about my phrasing "more gentle" or "softer" do those terms describe what you're looking for?

Comment: @Byte56 Kind of, In lack of better terms I would say I am trying to get from maze-like to a more cloudy texture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The noise function is returning a single "frequency" of noise. The effect on the right (B) is by adding together noise of multiple frequencies, in a "red noise" or "fractal brownian noise" pattern. Low frequencies will be more prominent than high frequencies.

You can change the frequency by multiplying the input to the noise function by a constant. For example, `noise(2*x,2*y)` will have frequency 2. So try adding `16*noise1(x,y) + 8*noise2(2*x,2*y) + 4*noise3(4*x,4*y) + 2*noise4(8*x,8*y) + noise5(16*x,16*y)` where `noise1`…`noise5` are `new Perlin(…)` with different seeds, and see if that's closer to what you want. I don't know for sure whether these constants will be what you need but you can start playing with them to get different effects.

Comment: I added an interactive demo. See the Octaves section of [this page](http://www.redblobgames.com/maps/terrain-from-noise/).